# C# lambda - keys array to values array

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

How can the following `GetValues` method be implemented using lambda expression?

```
public object[] GetValues(string[] keys, Dictionary<string, object> map) 
{
    // A simple non-lambda implementation
    object[] values = new object[keys.Length];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < keys.Length ; i++) 
    {
        values[i] = map[keys[i]];
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Well a combination of `Select` and `ToArray` seems to be the obvious approach - what have you tried?

Comment: I know it's a `lambda` (probably also `C#`) begginer's question, yet I am a begginer so everything fits. Have tried a few things, but didn't know about `Select`. Iwill take a look at it.

Comment: By "lambda expression" do you mean Linq-to-objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array.ConvertAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
object[] res = Array.ConvertAll(keys, x => map[x]);
```

(note that "technically" I'm not using LINQ, because `Array.Convert` isn't properly part of LINQ because it predates it, and I'm using a lambda **function** not a lambda **expression**)

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
return keys.Select(key => map[key]).ToArray();
```

If you're not sure that `map` contains the `key` use this:

```
return keys.Where(key => map.ContainsKey(key))
           .Select(key => map[key]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Looks simply perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @Elist It's worth mentioning that you'll get a `KeyNotFoundException` with this approach if you supply a key not present in the dictionary.

Comment: I first use `if (keys.All(key => map.ContainsKey(key)))` to vaidate

Comment: The map is actually a cache, if it doesn't contain all keys this method will not be called.